# How to extract information from the content of /proc files on Linux using C?

Tags: c, linux, fedora

I have been working on this for over 7 hours a day for 5 days. I am not exactly the best coder, so I need some help. I need to know how should I get the info from /proc using a C program on Linux.
The info has to be printed out and include the following:

- The complete command line for the process.
- State of the process.
- The PID of the parent.
- Priority.
- The nice value.
- Real­time  scheduling priority.
- CPU number last executed on.
- Amount of time that this process has been scheduled  in  user  mode.
- Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in kernel  mode.
- Virtual memory size in bytes.
- Total program size in pages.
- Resident Set Size (RSS) in bytes.
- Resident Set Size (RSS): number of pages the process has in real memory in 
  pages.
- Text (code) size in pages.
- Data + stack size in pages.
- Page table entries size in KB.
- Size of data in KB.
- Size of stack in KB.
- Size of text segment KB.

Comment: **match the example bellow**  which one ?

Comment: @PedroLobito the editor put everything in  one line 
the out put should be 
the compete command line for the process
state of the process , 
pid of the parent 
priority , and so on , there is few more if you looked up,  thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you don't know where to start. Let me try to explain the information in `/proc`:

If we `cat /proc/29519/stat`, we get this info:

`29519 (vim) S 5997 29519 5997 34835 29519 24576 1275 0 47 0 5 0 0 0 20 0 2 0 49083340 188043264 3718 18446744073709551615 4194304 6665820 140737488349264 140737488347024 140737280970147 0 0 12288 1837256447 18446744073709551615 0 0 17 3 0 0 21 0 0 8764120 8861948 8925184 140737488349925 140737488349929 140737488349929 140737488351211 0`

What do all those numbers represent? The answer is in [man proc](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc), in the section called `/proc/[pid]/stat`. From this we see the first four things are:

> pid %d
>
> (1) The process ID.
>
> comm %s
>
> (2) The filename of the executable, in parentheses. This is visible
>   whether or not the executable is swapped out.
>
> state %c
>
> (3) One character from the string "RSDZTW" where R is running, S is
>   sleeping in an interruptible wait, D is waiting in uninterruptible
>   disk sleep, Z is zombie, T is traced or stopped (on a signal), and W
>   is paging.
>
> ppid %d
>
> (4) The PID of the parent.

With this knowledge we can parse it out with `fscanf(f, "%d %s %c %d", ...)`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int pid;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &pid);
    printf("pid = %d\n", pid);

    char filename[1000];
    sprintf(filename, "/proc/%d/stat", pid);
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");

    int unused;
    char comm[1000];
    char state;
    int ppid;
    fscanf(f, "%d %s %c %d", &unused, comm, &state, &ppid);
    printf("comm = %s\n", comm);
    printf("state = %c\n", state);
    printf("parent pid = %d\n", ppid);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Now if I compile that file and run `./a.out 29519`, I get

```
pid = 29519
comm = (vim)
state = S
parent pid = 5997
```

Does that give you enough information to get started?

Comment: yes, I am a having a hard time to start , and been trying to find the starting point for a long time , thanks for the info , I will try it out  , and try to complete the task hopefully will be able to do it right , Thanks for  the help :D

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again, I am trying to compile the file, and it always give me one line which is the PID, then give me an error (segmentation fault (core dumped) )

Comment: Yes, when you run `./a.out <pid>`, the `pid` has to be the pid of a running program. `29519` is a valid pid on my computer, but probably not yours. To see some valid pids, try running `ps a`. All of the numbers on the left are pids.

Comment: yea , was willing to get back to you about that, I figured out later what was the issue, but really thank you so much for the help, If I may ask one more thing , as for the fscanf ,.. If I want to ship some values, I tried so , the values were all missed up.. how can I skip something I dont want to scan and then scan the rest. 
Thanks .

Comment: Use `%*d` (or `%*s`, `%*c`, etc.). For example, instead of writing `fscanf(f, "%d %s %c %d", &unused, comm, &state, &ppid);`, I could have written `fscanf(f, "%*d %s %c %d", comm, &state, &ppid);`.